# Want to filter the json objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having json objects with parent and child combination. I need to filter only the keys which matches the condition in child key/value pair.

response json is below,

I tried by using lodash filter and pickup and some more thing and result is only getting the child objects. But i need the output with including parent objects as well

```
    "custom": {
          "url": "",
          "version": ""
    },
    "apple": {
        "path": "www.testing.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
    "mango": {
        "path": "www.mango.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
    "pineapple": {
        "path": "www.pineapple.com",
        "version": "4.4"
    },
    "jackfruit": {
        "path": "www.jackfruit.com",
        "version": "4.3"
    }
```

Here, i need to filter only the objects which has version=4.5 and version="".

i need to filter the above json like below,

```
    "custom": {
        "url": "",
        "version": ""
    },
    "apple": {
        "path": "www.testing.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
    "mango": {
        "path": "www.mango.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
```

Please let me know how to make this possible.

Comment: `. I need to filter only the keys which matches the condition in child key/value pair.` What is the condition ?

Comment: *My code is below,* I don't see any code. All I see is partial input data and output format.

Comment: Sorry for unclear post. This is my first question in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguity. According to your input/output sample, I guess code below is what you need:

```js
let data = {   "custom": {
          "url": "",
          "version": ""
    },
    "apple": {
        "path": "www.testing.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
    "mango": {
        "path": "www.mango.com",
        "version": "4.5"
    },
    "pineapple": {
        "path": "www.pineapple.com",
        "version": "4.4"
    },
    "jackfruit": {
        "path": "www.jackfruit.com",
        "version": "4.3"
    }}


let result = _.pickBy(data,(v,k)=>v.version === "4.5" || v.version ==="" )
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. But you have provided the exact thing what I need. Thank you so much :)